# Could we use also use $\delta_1,\delta_2$,or do we have to use the same $\delta$?

Tags: analysis

I am looking at the following exercise:
$f,g:A \to R$ are uniformly continuous at $A$.If we suppose that $f,g$ are bounded,prove that $f \cdot g:A \to R$ is uniformly continuous at $A$.
I have thought to do it like that:
Let $\epsilon'>0$.Since $f$ is uniformly continuous at $A$, there is a $\delta_1$ such that $\forall x,y \in A$ with $$|x-y|<\delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon'$$
Since,g is uniformly continuous at $A$,there is a $\delta_2$ such that $\forall x,y \in A$ with $$|x-y|<\delta_2 \Rightarrow |g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon'$$
We set $\delta=min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$.
Therefore,we have :$\forall x,y \in A$ with $$|x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |(fg)(x)-(fg)(y)|=|f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y)|=|f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(y)+f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(y)|\leq|f(x)||g(x)-g(y)|+|g(y)||f(x)-f(y)|$$
$f$ is bounded,so there is a $M>0$ such that $\forall x,y \in A:|f(x)|\leq M$.
Also,$g$ is bounded,so there is a $N>0$ such that $\forall x,y \in A:|g(x)|\leq N$.
So,$|(fg)(x)-(fg)(y)|<\epsilon'(M+N)$.We set $\epsilon'=\frac{\epsilon}{M+N}$.So,we have that: $|(fg)(x)-(fg)(y)|<\epsilon$,so $f \cdot g$ is uniformly continuous.

BUT,in my textbook,they don't take $\delta_1,\delta_2$,when they use the definition that $f,g$ is uniformly continuous but the same $\delta$.Is the way that I did it wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing it wrong.

For each $\varepsilon$, knowing that $f$ is uniformly continuous gives you a $\delta$ that works for $f$, and knowing that $g$ is uniformly continuous gives you a possibly different $\delta$ that works for $g$.

As you observe, the minimum of these two $\delta$s actually works for both $f$ and $g$ (because of what exactly it means to "work" in this context).

If your textbooks jumps directly to having a single $\delta$ that works for both functions, it must be because it is *implying* exactly the reasoning you're writing out in full (and leaving it to the reader to figure out what goes on).